# Enable logging for SSH session on Brocade FCX Switch

Tags: ssh, logging, switch, brocade

On my Brocade FCX switch, I'm able to see syslog messages in-line when I'm using a console cable by running the command logging console from the configuration menu. However, when I SSH in, I'm unable to see the syslog messages in-line. On Cisco switches, I know the command is logging monitor to do this, but it doesn't seem to work on the Brocade FCX switches. Does anyone know the command to do this?

The firmware I'm running on is 7.4b. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I talked to our reseller and found out how to do it.

First ensure logging is on and enable console logging

```
configure terminal
logging on
logging console
```

Then exit out of configuration mode and enable logging for ssh

```
exit
terminal monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

debug destination logging ssh < session number 1-5 >

Use **show who** to find your session number.

[Reference](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/product_manuals/B_FastIron/FastIron_07400_Diagnostic.pdf)

Comment: This does not work, it's possible to enter a debugging mode through a modification for this command (the above format is incorrect) but this does not enable general logging.